# use an event for each case (javascript switch)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to specify `e.preventDefault()` once  that will be work as same as the below code.

I mean I don't want to write `e.preventDefault()` each time if possible...

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) { // Ctrl+
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 79: // O
        e.preventDefault();
        openDoc();
        break;
      case 83: // S
        e.preventDefault();
        saveDoc();
        break;
      case 66: // B
        e.preventDefault();
        showHideStatusBar(showStatusBar ? false : true);
        break;
      case 191: // /
        e.preventDefault();
        Help();
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The `e` object doesn't change from when the function is called, so you can call it wherever you want. Have you tried putting it before the `switch`?

Comment: You could put a flag in each one of your cases (shouldPrevent = true) and after the switch check shouldPrevent to see if it's true.

Comment: @Nunners I think he may be only wanting to prevent default if one of the cases match.

Comment: @CalebJoshuaMingle yea you're right... i only want to prevent default if one of the cases match..

Comment: The example isn't very good then because `e.preventDefault()` is called on each case. Anyway adding a flag would just make you type more, not less.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind not wanting to do e.preventDefault() in each case?  There's a few different things you could do but it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish with it (more actions may be added in the future, you don't want to duplicate e.preventDefault, etc).

Comment: I just want to simplify code...

Comment: The only real solutions that I can think of are with that in mind: a) set a flag, b) create a new function that calls preventDefault and call that function instead, c) do some logic beforehand that pretty much duplicates your cases and if they match call preventDefault, d) create a new function that gets passed a function or function pointer that calls e.preventDefault() and then your custom function (openDoc, etc).  All in all, you're not really going to save anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
if (e.ctrlKey) { // Ctrl+
    if (/^(79|83|66|191)$/.test(e.keyCode){
     e.preventDefault();
    }
    switch (e.keyCode) { /*... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place `e.preventDefault()` before the `switch`

Comment: @user2947116 Please edit the question then. Your example has `e.preventDefault()` for more than one case.